# A Batch create new file not working

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch file that checks a file if its empty or not. if its empty then create another file howerver the below code is not working can you tell me why

```
echo on
echo hi
rem =========================================================
FOR %%F IN (file*new.*) DO (
IF %%~zF LSS 8 ( 
echo . >empty.sql
)
```

edit FULL SCRIPT

```
echo. off

rem =========================================================
FOR %%F IN (file*new.*) DO (
IF %%~zF LSS 8 ( 
echo . >empty.pbd
)

echo. >> FILE_NEW.SQL
@echo UPDATE TAB1 SET A='B' >> FILE_NEW.SQL
@echo / >>FILE_NEW.SQL
@echo COMMIT>>FILE_NEW.SQL
@echo / >>FILE_NEW.SQL
)
pause
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't tell us what isn't working, I can only guess ...

- You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end, so that's a syntax error, which should also provide a nice error message for you.
- You create a new file that contains a dot, a space, and a line break. If you want an empty new file use

  ```
  copy nul empty.sql
  ```

  instead.
- You check for the file size being less than 8 bytes, which isn't the same definition for »empty file« I'd use.

Comment: please check my edit if I remove the last 5 echos , it will work